# Efficiency clarification: Asking subsets of a general turtle type or asking breeds?

Tags: netlogo

I'm working with a large model with many agents executing many procedures each day.

Is it better to do something as such:

```
ask turtles [
 if type = "A" [do-A-thing]
 if type = "B" [do-B-thing]
]
```

or alternatively

```
ask A-turtles [do-A-thing]
ask B-turtles [do-B-thing]
```

I'm looking to lower the computational load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that tries both of your approaches. It creates 100,000 turtles and executes the test 1,000 times for each case. Approach 2 seems faster. On my machine, approach 1 took 46.3 seconds, and approach 2 took 30.6 seconds. It doesn't help much to use an *ifelse* in approach 1. It seems logical that approach 2 is faster, since you avoid comparisons.

```
breed[A-turtles A-turtle]
breed[B-turtles B-turtle]

turtles-own [
 typ
]

; setup button callback function
to setup
  clear-all

  ; create turtles for approach 1
  create-turtles 100000
  ask turtles [
   ifelse (who < 50000) [
     set typ "A"
   ]
   [
     set typ "B"
   ]
  ]

 ; time approach 1
 let i 0
 let iter 1000
 reset-timer
 while [ i < iter ]
  [
    ; approach 1
    ask turtles [
      if typ = "A" [
        doSomething
      ]
      if typ = "B" [
        doSomething
      ]
    ]
    set i i + 1
  ]
  print (word "approach 1 time: " timer " secs")

  ; delete turtles, then create turtles for approach 2
  clear-all
  clear-turtles
  create-A-turtles 50000
  create-B-turtles 50000

  ; time approach 2
  set i 0
  reset-timer
  while [ i < iter ]
  [
    ; approach 2
    ask A-turtles [ doSomething ]
    ask B-turtles [ doSomething ]
    set i i + 1
  ]
  print (word "approach 2 time: " timer " secs")

end

to doSomething
  let i 0
  set i i + 1
  set i i - 1
end
```

Comment: I just tested it myself and got similar numbers to you. I think this is something I might need to change in my code unfortunately.

Comment: @AndrewYoak If you haven't already, definitely check out the [`profiler` extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/profiler.html) to help you identify any bottlenecks in your code.